# I have found this fossil tooth, could it be pliosaur ? Or maybe theropod?

Tags: fossils, paleontology

[image]

**Lenght: 10 mm, striated, circular cross-section**

**Site: Brno-Hády (limestone quarry), Moravia, Czech republic, central Europa**

**Age: Jurassic, oxford**

The site is a good source of fossil shark teeth, but this tooth I am wondering about has absolutely different structure and does not have as strong luster as shark teeth have.

An example of shark tooth fossil from Brno-Hády site:
[image]
[See my shark-tooth photos here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/violetplanet/26006990296/in/album-72157665693696130/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely plesiosaur. That fluted structure is indicative of marine reptile teeth. My first guess was mosasaur but their are a lot of plesiosaurs from that formation so I would go with that. It is obviously a shed tooth which makes it harder. shark teeth flare out at the base becasue they attach differently than marine reptile teeth, sharks need more surface area for a strong connection.  Hopefully a marine reptile person can give you a tighter identification, I mostly work on dinosaurs.